# Self-hosted NancyFX with Windsor view compilation error defined in not referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, nancy

Got an app with NancyFX, self hosted across multiple projects (self-host is running on Topshelf as a service/console app for debugging).

Replaced TinyIoC strapper with Windsor strapper.

Added registrations.

Added Castle.Windsor reference to all assemblies in project

Got this error:

> [CS0012] Line: 128 Column: 18 - The type 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IWindsorInstaller' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Castle.Windsor, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'. (show)

Tried adding

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Castle.Windsor, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

To app.config - nothing.

Comment: Have you tried asking the same in NancyFx Chat room ? i

Comment: I have, doesn't look too promising though :(